# How to default a MySQL date (timestamp) field to now

Tags: mysql, sql

I have tried

```
alter table t_granja ALTER COLUMN purchase_date TIMESTAMP DEFAULT now();
```

but I got an error

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'TIMESTAMP DEFAULT now()' at line 1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`

```
ALTER TABLE t_granja 
ALTER COLUMN purchase_date TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;
```